# Python regex to find multiple consecutive punctuations

Tags: python, regex, mapreduce

I am streaming plain text records via MapReduce and need to check each plain text record for 2 or more consecutive punctuation symbols. The 12 symbols I need to check for are: `-/\()!"+,'&.`.

I have tried translating this punctuation list into an array like this:
punctuation = `[r'-', r'/', r'\\', r'\(', r'\)', r'!', r'"', r'\+', r',', r"'", r'&', r'\.']`

I can find individual characters with nested for loops, for example:

```
for t in test_cases:
    print t
    for p in punctuation:
        print p
        if re.search(p, t):
            print 'found a match!', p, t
        else:
            print 'no match'
```

However, the single backslash character is not found when I test this and I don't know how to get only results that are 2 or more consecutive occurrences in a row. I've read that I need to use the + symbol, but don't know the correct syntax to use this.

Here are some test cases:

```
The quick '''brown fox
The &&quick brown fox
The quick\brown fox
The quick\\brown fox
The -quick brown// fox
The quick--brown fox
The (quick brown) fox,,,
The quick ++brown fox
The "quick brown" fox
The quick/brown fox
The quick&brown fox
The ""quick"" brown fox
The quick,, brown fox
The quick brown fox…
The quick-brown fox
The ((quick brown fox
The quick brown)) fox
The quick brown fox!!!
The 'quick' brown fox
```

Which when translated into a Pythonic list looks like this:

```
test_cases = [
"The quick '''brown fox",
'The &&quick brown fox',
'The quick\\brown fox',
'The quick\\\\brown fox',
'The -quick brown// fox',
'The quick--brown fox',
'The (quick brown) fox,,,',
'The quick ++brown fox',
'The "quick brown" fox',
'The quick/brown fox',
'The quick&brown fox',
'The ""quick"" brown fox',
'The quick,, brown fox',
'The quick brown fox...',
'The quick-brown fox',
'The ((quick brown fox',
'The quick brown)) fox',
'The quick brown fox!!!',
"The 'quick' brown fox" ]
```

How do I use Python regex to identify and report all matches where the punctuation symbol appears 2 or more times in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The punctuation characters can be put into a character class is square brackets.
Then it depends, whether the series of two or more punctuation characters consists of any punctuation character or whether the punctuation characters are the same.

In the first case curly braces can be appended to specify the number of minimum (2) and maximum repetitions. The latter is unbounded and left empty:

```
[...]{2,} # min. 2 or more
```

If only repetitions of the same character needs to be found, then the first matched punctuation character is put into a group. Then the same group (= same character) follows one or more:

```
([...])\1+
```

The back reference `\1` means the first group in the expression. The groups, represented by the opening parentheses are numbered from left to right.

The next issue is escaping. There are escaping rules for Python strings and additional escaping is needed in the regular expression. The character class does not require much escaping, but the backslash must be doubled. Thus the
following example quadruplicates the backslash, one doubling because of the string, the second because of the regular expression.

Raw strings `r'...'` are useful for patterns, but here both the single and double quotation marks are needed.

```
>>> import re
>>> test_cases = [
    "The quick '''brown fox",
    'The &&quick brown fox',
    'The quick\\brown fox',
    'The quick\\\\brown fox',
    'The -quick brown// fox',
    'The quick--brown fox',
    'The (quick brown) fox,,,',
    'The quick ++brown fox',
    'The "quick brown" fox',
    'The quick/brown fox',
    'The quick&brown fox',
    'The ""quick"" brown fox',
    'The quick,, brown fox',
    'The quick brown fox...',
    'The quick-brown fox',
    'The ((quick brown fox',
    'The quick brown)) fox',
    'The quick brown fox!!!',
    "The 'quick' brown fox" ]
>>> pattern_any_punctuation = re.compile('([-/\\\\()!"+,&\'.]{2,})')
>>> pattern_same_punctuation = re.compile('(([-/\\\\()!"+,&\'.])\\2+)')
>>> for t in test_cases:
    match = pattern_same_punctuation.search(t)
    if match:
        print("{:24} => {}".format(t, match.group(1)))
    else:
        print(t)

The quick '''brown fox   => '''
The &&quick brown fox    => &&
The quick\brown fox
The quick\\brown fox     => \\
The -quick brown// fox   => //
The quick--brown fox     => --
The (quick brown) fox,,, => ,,,
The quick ++brown fox    => ++
The "quick brown" fox
The quick/brown fox
The quick&brown fox
The ""quick"" brown fox  => ""
The quick,, brown fox    => ,,
The quick brown fox...   => ...
The quick-brown fox
The ((quick brown fox    => ((
The quick brown)) fox    => ))
The quick brown fox!!!   => !!!
The 'quick' brown fox
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that confuses me is the doubling of the backslashes. My input will have double backslashes that I want to capture as a double backslash, but my test cases required quad backslashes in order to detect the double backslash. How to I make sure that what appears to be double backslash in the input stream is caught as a double backslash rather than a single?

Comment: Inside Python strings without prefix `r` the backslash is doubled. Also the @ChrisNielsen The backslash needs to be doubled inside regular expressions, when used as normal character. Therefore you will need four backslashes inside a regular expression inside a Python string (without prefix `r`) to get one one backslash.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: In your explanation you used `\1`, but in the code for same punctuation you used `\\2`. Why is that?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen The first backslash escapes the second backslash in the python string literal using `'...'`. The first backslash can be avoided by using `r'...'`. I have not used the latter, because it does not make the code more readable because both string quote characters are part of the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{2}` in a regular expression to match two consecutive occurrences of a character class:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'[-/()!"+,\'&]{2}')
>>> [s for s in test_cases if regex.search(s)]
["The quick '''brown fox",
 'The &&quick brown fox',
 'The -quick brown// fox',
 'The quick--brown fox',
 'The (quick brown) fox,,,',
 'The quick ++brown fox',
 'The ""quick"" brown fox',
 'The quick,, brown fox',
 'The ((quick brown fox',
 'The quick brown)) fox',
 'The quick brown fox!!!']
```

Comment: The only problem I can see is that it is not finding the case of the double backslash \\.

Comment: The back slash wasn't in the list of characters when I answered. (At least it didn't show up in the rendered question.  It might have been in the source code, but didn't show up because it's the escape character.)  You can just add it.

Answer (score 0):

What about regular expression? That could also help to find 2 or more consecutive punctuation symbols.

RegEx like `\([\\\-\/\(\)!"+,'&]{2,})\g`

`{2,}` stands for two or more

`\g` stands for global search, dont stop on first match

Comment: Yes, I would like to use a regular expression (regex). The question is what is the syntax to do this..

Comment: you could play around on [regex101](https://regex101.com) an online regex tester.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use what you have above because there is no mention of test_cases. How do you actually USE what you have pasted above? re.compile and then re.search?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Heiko Oberdiek, here is the exact code I am using that solves the problem: (I added . to the punctuation list)

```
punctuation = re.compile('(([-/\\\\()!"+,&\'.])\\2+)')
x = 1
for t in test_cases:
    match = punctuation.search(t)
    if match:
        print "{0:2} {1:24} => {2}".format(x, t, match.group(1))
        x += 1
```

This accurately covers all of my test cases:

```
 1 The quick '''brown fox   => '''
 2 The &&quick brown fox    => &&
 3 The quick\\brown fox     => \\
 4 The -quick brown// fox   => //
 5 The quick--brown fox     => --
 6 The (quick brown) fox,,, => ,,,
 7 The quick ++brown fox    => ++
 8 The ""quick"" brown fox  => ""
 9 The quick,, brown fox    => ,,
10 The quick brown fox...   => ...
11 The ((quick brown fox    => ((
12 The quick brown)) fox    => ))
13 The quick brown fox!!!   => !!!
```